# Password protect pdf file in php

Tags: php, pdf, encryption

In my web app, a user can upload pdf file and can read it later. Is there any way to password protect the file while uploading. So that if the file is accessed without the application, it can't be opened without password.
But when a user tries to open the file from the web application, it will not require password.

Comment: https://mpdf.github.io/reference/mpdf-functions/setprotection.html

Comment: The requirements seem contradictory - you want to upload it, and add a password such that if the user opens it within the web app (i.e. I assume they click on a link, it downloads the file to their temp folder and then displays it in the browser...or are you displaying it within a JS-based viewer in a frame or something?) it doesn't require a password...but yet if they somehow open it "outside the application" it does. This is unworkable - opening the file is not really your application's job for a start - the browser normally handles it, so you don't have much control.

Comment: ...and if a file is password protected, then it's password protected. It cannot know who is trying to open it. In fact, think about it - if the file knew who was trying to open it, there would be no need for a password at all - it could simply allow or deny access based on that. It's not really clear what you're trying to achieve. If you think you can stop the file being downloaded and copied, you're out of luck. Even _displaying_ the document in the browser causes it to be copied to the user's machine, even in a temp folder. From there they can save it permanently. You can't prevent that.

Comment: A password will make it harder for others to open it when they receive a copy, but the user who downloaded it originally would have needed the password to open it, so they can simply share the password along with the document if they so choose.

Comment: It's impossible. End of story.